# How to tell if a series converges/diverges based on if the sequence converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Maybe a stupid question, but if a sequence converges, can it be predicted that the series will also converge?

Comment: Snort answer: no.

Comment: Longer answer, there exist sequences who converge whose series does not as well as sequences who converge whose series does.  You can note that a sequence who does not converge will necessarily have the corresponding series not converge either.  Also, you can note that a sequence who converges but does not converge to zero will necessarily have the corresponding series not converge.  A sequence converging to zero however might still have the corresponding series diverge.

Comment: For simple examples, consider $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 0,~\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k,~\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k},~\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 1$

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of examples that serve to illustrate that it difficult to make general statements about whether or not a series converges, based solely on the convergence of the terms of the series:

**The sequence converges but the series diverges**

$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\ldots
$$

(If a series is convergent, then its terms must approach $0$. However, the converse is not true: if the terms approach $0$, then the series is not necessarily convergent, as shown by the example above.)

**The sequence and the series both converge**

$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots
$$

**The sequence and the series both diverge**

$$
1-1+1-1+\ldots
$$

**The sequence diverges but the series converges**

(No examples here. The [divergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand) says that if the limit of the sequence is non-zero, or does not exist, then the series diverges.)